# Shell Script does not work

Tags: shell, unix, racket

I created a racket file, which I named shl.rkt. The file starts with

```
#! /usr/local/bin/racket
```

I go to the directory of the file and type   `./shl.rkt`. However, it outputs bad interpreter: No such file or directory. Why is that? I am using a MAC.

I also realised that my "which racket" command outputs nothing. What should I do to fix it?

Comment: Sounds like you need to put wherever racket is installed into your `$PATH`

Comment: If `which racket` doesn't give you the path to `racket`, you have to install it first...

Comment: Don't think this has anything to do with $PATH.

Comment: Does `/usr/local/bin/racket` exist? Also, remove the space after the `#!`.

Comment: Try 'whereis racket'

Answer (score 3):

On the Mac, the `racket` executable is `/Applications/Racket v6.4/bin/racket` (for Racket 6.4, the current version at the time of writing). [Unfortunately, it is not possible for shebang lines to refer to interpreters with spaces in the path.](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-bash/2008-05/msg00053.html) So you will need to make a symlink to that. If you want `/usr/local/bin/racket` to work, then make that a symlink to `/Applications/Racket v6.4/bin/racket`.

Answer (score 0):

Update:

Make sure that:

```
ls /usr/local/bin/racket
```

shows a file. If it does, then add /usr/local/bin/ to the $PATH var:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin
```

and retry